# Checking if an element has a specific class in jquery not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stopped up with a very simple functionality that worked with me many times back but not working right now.No specific errors in console also.

I am trying to check if there is a specific class for a div containing `.form-content.inactive` classes.I am trying to find if there is another class `opened` .

### My codes are below mentioned

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($('.form-content.inactive').hasClass('opened')){
     $(".form-content a").click(function(event) {
        alert('has');
     });
  } 
});
```

No alerts are given on click.I am stupid now for a while :p

Comment: Is `opened` and/or `inactive` class added dynamically after page load?

Comment: Is `$('.form-content.inactive).length > 0` true? Otherwise the element doesn't exist, or your query is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `div` hasn't the class `opened` from the beginning, you should do it this way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".form-content a").click(function(event) {
         if($('.form-content.inactive').hasClass('opened')){
            alert('has');
        } 
     });
});
```

Otherwise your code could work.. When your `div` has the class `opened` already before the document became ready, only then jQuery is able to subscribe your click element to the event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.form-content.inactive').hasClass('opened')) {
    $(".form-content a").click(function(event) {
      alert('has');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-content inactive opened">
  <a>Click!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is true, but answers that include only code and no explanation on not as helpful as they could be.

Comment: I know, trying to now.

Comment: this could cause unexpected behaviour if there are multiple `.form-content` elements.

Comment: True, I didn't say your answer isn't better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for `opened` you could use a delegate:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body').on('click', '.form-content.inactive.opened a', function(event) {
    alert('has');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-content inactive opened">
  <a>Link</a>
</div>
```

This will fire the click event for `a` if the `.form-content` has both classes `.inactive` and `.opened`.

If you insist on using `hasClass` and you have multiple `.form-content` then you should use `this` to get the closest `.form-content` and check for both classes.

```
$(".form-content a").click(function(event) {

  var formContent = $(this).closest('.form-content');

  if(formContent.hasClass('inactive') && formContent.hasClass('opened')){
    alert('has');
  } 

});
```